# Flask Jinja2 for loop

Tags: html, flask, jinja2, boto, boto3

I have this python script below which list the instance id, state and type of 
AWS EC2 instances. This is working fine as you can see below.

```
[root@localhost ec2]# cat ec2.py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import boto3

ec2client = boto3.client('ec2')
response = ec2client.describe_instances()

for reservation in response["Reservations"]:
        for instance in reservation["Instances"]:
                print "{0}\t{1}\t{2}".format(instance["InstanceId"], 
instance["State"]["Name"], instance["InstanceType"])

[root@localhost ec2]# ./ec2.py
i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx     stopped t2.small
i-yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy     running t2.medium
i-zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz     stopped t2.medium
i-bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb     stopped t2.small
i-ccccccccccccccccc     running t2.medium
```

Now I am trying to display above output in a web page using Flask. But I am 
getting error saying """
File "/flask/ec2/app.py", line 15, in list_instances
instances = reservations["Instances"]
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
"""

This is what I did till now

```
[root@localhost ec2]# cat app.py
import boto3
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)


ec2client = boto3.client('ec2')
response = ec2client.describe_instances()

@app.route("/")
def list_instances():
       reservations = response["Reservations"]
       instances = reservations["Instances"]
       return render_template("ec2.html", instances=instances)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=5000, debug=True, host="0.0.0.0")

[root@localhost ec2]# cat templates/ec2.html
<html>
<head>
       <title>EC2 List</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>EC2 List</h1>
{% for instance in instances %}
<p>{{ instance }}</p>
{% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

Can somebody help me to fix this error and get the required output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example `reservations` is a list, so you should iterate over it using `for reservation in reservations` before trying to access `reservation['Instances']`.

Comment: Thanks now it is working. I used 'instances=response["Reservations"]' in 
 app.py and looped over to instances in my html.